# inserting web form data into ms-access using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to take data from a web form and place it in an ms-access database.  The code which is in the `aspx.vb` page (to date) is listed below but when I run it the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` throws up

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Why is this?  What should the code read?

```
  Protected Sub RegButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RegButton.Click
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim Sql As String

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Users.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"

    con.Open()

    Sql = "INSERT INTO Users.Personnel (FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Username, UserPassword) VALUES (@first, @last, @addr, @email, @uname, @pwd) "
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("saved")

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", FirstBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", LastBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr", AddressBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", EmailBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UserBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", PwdBox.Text)

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not execute query before passing parameters try this.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Users.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"

con.Open()

Sql = "INSERT INTO Users.Personnel (FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, Username, UserPassword) VALUES (@first, @last, @addr, @email, @uname, @pwd) "
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)


cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", FirstBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", LastBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr", AddressBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", EmailBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UserBox.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", PwdBox.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("saved")
con.Close()
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks Amit.  A simple solution which makes me feel simple for not spotting it!!